# XmlSerializer and acceptable values

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xsd, xml-parsing

Hello I am working on an project in which I should serialize and deserialize my objects to Xml and back to objects. I use the XmlSerializer class in order to achieve this. So my problem is that I can't figure out how to prevent the serialization if the attribute value of an element is invalid. For example I have an element with name person which contain 1 attribute (name) 

I would like to prevent the user to put other names than (Alex, Nick,..) in this attribute I need something like xsd restriction (pattern) in this case but for my model. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Just so its clear: you want to restrict the values of the element/attribute?

Comment: I don't think serializing should do data validation.  Data validation should occur before serialization takes place.

Comment: Maess I neeed the restriction for attribute.

Comment: What is it you want to do? Perform validation? (and throw an exception?)? Or: conditionally include/exclude that member? Or...?

Comment: Mark: In this case is a validation I would like to make it is without using the xsd file if it possible.

Comment: Can you rephrase? I can't quite parse that line...

Comment: I would like to avoid using the xsd file and make the validation directly in my model library. If it is possible.

Comment: And do you want it to throw an exception? Or just skip the incorrect value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure weather it is a good idea to ignore some data in certain circumstances, but if you really wanna do this, take a look at the [IXmlSerializable Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx). I think implementing this interface manually will be the only way to fulfill your requirements.

Comment: There are much easiser ways of getting conditional XML serialisation. I'm not sure that is the requirement, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want conditional serialisation, you can do this with the ShouldSerialize* pattern. So if you have a property `Name` (for example), you can add:

```
public bool ShouldSerializeName() {
    /* validate; return true to serialize, false to skip */
}
```

The method needs to be public for XmlSerializer, although the same pattern works in other places (System.ComponentModel, for example) even if no-public.

Comment: +1 for actually noting that the function must be public for XmlSerializer. This is the first place I've even seen it mentioned.